# jquery menu inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple 3 level menu structure:

```
<nav class="main-nav" class="list">
  <ul>
    <li class="first lev1"><a href="">Home</a></li>        
    <li class="lev1"><a href="">Lev 1 1</a></li>
    <li class="lev1 hasc active">
      <a href="">Lev 1 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="first lev2 hasc">
          <a href="">Lev 2 1</a>        
          <ul>
            <li class="first lev3"><a href=""></a>Lev 3 1 </li>
            <li class="lev3"><a href="">Lev 3 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lev1 hasc active"><a href="">Lev 1 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to make the menu work so that the second level menu slides open when it has children but is an active link when it does not and then all 3rd level links are always active links.

The following jquery code works for all the required functionality for the 2nd level menu (prevents default and opens the 3rd level if there are children, but if not makes the link active) the problem is that i'm not sure how to over ride the prevent default for the third level?

```
$(".lev2").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('on');
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('on');
    }
});
```

I've looked into starting at the root of the menu class 'main-nav' and then try to branch the code but as it is nested I'm not finding any logic that will work? any ideas most welcome.

Comment: Damn.  I know what the issue is, I just can't get anything to work.  Your click event is just bubbling up from the lev3 to the lev2 which is triggering the preventDefault.  I just can't write a selector that says .lev2 and NOT .lev3 click().

Comment: Something like `$('.lev2').not('.lev3')` ?

Comment: Exactly. I glad I've written it well enough for you to see the problem

Comment: I tried that.  Also tried `$("li.lev2:not(li.lev3)")`

Comment: How are you managing the first level? In the same way as the second? ...thinking of writing a single function to include all levels.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I did try something similar to this before and tried your suggestion just now, but still nothing - If I write out the class's that lev3 has it seems to inherit the lev2 class which kills this kind of test.

Comment: First level is a static left hand col menu. lev2 then displays on hover to the right of the first lev and then lev3 drops down under lev 2.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a work around.

Comment: Replace `$(".lev2").click(...)` with `$('.lev2 > a').click(...)` to bind the `click event` to the link rather than the whole `li`.

Comment: @Stefan That actually sounds like a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  Just checks for a level 3 click first to tell the level 2 function whether level 3 has been clicked or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var level2 = true;
    $("li.lev3").click(function(){
        level2 = false;
    });
    $("li.lev2").click( function(event){
        if (level2){
            alert ("lvl2");
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
                $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
                $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).children('ul').slideDown(); 
                $(this).addClass('on');   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks James - your time very much appreciated, I'd happily buy you a beer should it be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you´re binding the `click event` to the entire `li` element and not just the link.

Try this instead:

```
$(".lev2 > a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('on').children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

It binds the `event` to the link and toggles your actions on the parent `li` and `ul` for the next level.

[Live example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3Bna/)